# How does one find the Taylor Series of $ f(x) = \frac{x^{3}}{x+1} $?

Tags: taylor-expansion

I know this is relatable to the geometric series:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{n} = f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x} = 1 + x + x^{2} + x^{3} + x^{4} + \ldots$$

But not sure what should or could be done in order to change the geometric series or the one in question to make the function into a Taylor Series, and an expand it  like the geometric series.

So I know that I can make the function in question look more like a geometric series:

$f(x) = \frac{x^{3}}{1-(-x)}$

but this is still not the right geometric form because of the $x^{3}$ on top.

Just feeling stuck here. Not sure if I should change the original geometric series to look more like the function in question, or to change the function in question to look more like the geometric series.

please help

Thank you

Comment: You're on the right track. Do $1/(1+x)$ and then multiply by $x^3$ when you're done. I don't know if you're supposed to give a proof that you're correct, but such things can be done by looking at an estimate of the $n$th order remainder term.

Comment: @TedShifrin, is absolutely correct.

Comment: @yre: You must first decide what point you want to expand around. There is not just one Taylor expansion of a function, but around a specific point.

Comment: @mathreadler Not sure here, but the question just asks to find the Taylor Series of this function. I've read (not sure) that when an about 'a' isn't given it's presumed to be a = 0 or a Maclaurin.

Comment: Should be specified around what point, because the series will only converge in a disc with a radius touching the nearest pole so the position is quite crucial for usability.

Comment: About a = 0 I think. Most of these practice problems have been about a = 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have

$$\frac {1-x^n}{1-x}=$$
$$1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4....+x^{n-1}$$ and
when $x $  satisfies the condition: $|x|<1,$
we have $\lim_{n\to+\infty}x^n=0$ and
$$\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}x^k .$$

As $|x|<1\implies |-x|<1$,
WE CAN REPLACE $x $ by $-x $ and get

$$\frac{1}{1-(-x)}=1-x+x^2-x^3+x^4-... $$

and

$$x^3\frac {1}{1+x}=x^3-x^4+x^5-... $$

$$=\sum_{n=3}^{+\infty}(-1)^{n+1}x^n $$

Comment: Thanks!
So to clarify my understanding of this. What you did was used what we know about the geometric series being 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + ....

and then changed the function we were given to fit the form of the geometric series, without changing the value of the function in question. You just took out x^3 and placed it to the side. What I am having trouble understanding is when you changed the function in question why did the series expansion start alternating negative and positive?

Comment: And so then after we knew what the series would look like from knowledge of the geometric series would could just put the original back into it's original form and then multiply it all by that x^3 that was slid off to the side.

Comment: if the exponent p is odd,$ (-x)^p=-x^p $

Comment: I think I understand. And when you write that |x| < 1 for the geometric series and that |-x|  < 1 for the other geometric series type. what values can I imagine being plugged in for x?

Comment: Doesn't the series start from n = 0 and build up from that?

Comment: You can replace $x $ by an expression $g (x) $ which also satisfies $|g (x)|<1$ like $-x $.

Comment: If x is always less than 1 wouldn't that mean that the denominator is always positive? so then how could it alternate?

Comment: They alternate, but their sum is positive.

Comment: 1-2+4-8+16 is positive

Comment: Thanks, I see that there sum is positive. The part that confuses me is where the alternating signs come from with: 1 - x + x^2 + ....

Comment: Where the first geometric series had all positive signs, why did the altered geometric sum begin changing signs?

Comment: $(- x)^2=(-x)(-x)=x^2$ but $(- x)^3=-x^3$  and $(- x)^5=-x^5$

Comment: I see! Thank you. So all that is happening is that the variables are being replaced in the original geometric series with (-x) instead of just (x).

Comment: Okay, the part that doesn't make sense then is how could 1/(1-x) equal 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + ..... I understand if you don't want to answer this conversation has carried on for awhile.

Comment: @yre Please look now. i edited some lines.

Comment: Thanks!
Why did you put a $ -x^{n} $ and then end the series with a $x^{n-1} $. How does this change things?

Comment: @yre for example 1+2+2^2+2^3=(1-2^4)(1-2) $

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand. Just need to practice and spend more time thinking about these type problems!
best

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach. Let $$f(x):=\left(\frac{x^3}{x+1}\right)$$

and using the general Leibniz rule for the product of derivatives we have that

$$\partial^nf(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\partial^k(x^3)\partial^{n-k}(x+1)^{-1}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}3^{\underline k}x^{3-k}(-1)^{\overline{n-k}}(x+1)^{-1-n+k}=\\=\frac{(-1)^nx^3 n!}{(x+1)^{n+1}}+\frac{(-1)^{n-1}3x^2 n!}{(x+1)^n}+\frac{(-1)^{n-2}3x n!}{(x+1)^{n-1}}+\frac{(-1)^{n-3}n!}{(x+1)^{n-2}}+0+...$$

Then from above you can search closed expressions for $f^{(k)}(a)$ to define the Taylor expansion of $f$ around $x=a$.

For example for $x=0$ we have that

$$f^{(k)}(0)=\begin{cases}(-1)^{k+1}k!,&k\ge 3\\0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Hence

$$\mathcal T(f,0)=\sum_{k=3}^\infty(-1)^{k+1}x^k,\quad |x|<1$$